# Access Web.Config path from ServerManager object

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I need to update a remote Web.config file and I currently have access to the application via the `ServerManager` object inside of the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly like so:

```
ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("::1");
Configuration configuration = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site", "/Application.Name");
```

Is there anyway I'm able to retrieve the path of the Web.config from this object so I can load it into `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` and modify it?

My initial thought was to use `ConfigurationElementCollection appSettings = configuration.GetSection("appSettings").GetCollection();` but I'm unable to access the configuration data that I need to modify using this method so need to use `XDocument` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found it. It looks like the only way to access it is like so:

```
ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("::1");
string physicalPath = manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[virtualDirPath].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath

string webConfigLocation = Path.Combine(physicalPath, "web.config");
```